# Filter design documents with PouchDB

Tags: filter, replication, pouchdb, design-documents

I'm using a design document to ensure that only owners can modify docs. How can I prevent couchdb from replicating this design document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [filter option](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) in `changes()` and `replicate()`, e.g.

```
var opts = {
  live: true,
  filter: function(doc) {
    return doc._id.indexOf('_design') !== 0;
  } 
};
var db = new PouchDB('todos');
db.replicate.to('http://localhost:5984/todos', opts);
```

Comment: Note: this is the default functionality when using https://github.com/redgeoff/factoryng, however, you can disable it using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436821/include-design-documents-factoryng/26436823#26436823