# Include design documents factoryng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb, design-documents

The default settings in [factoryng](http://github.com/redgeoff/factoryng) filter out design documents. How can I include these design documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this via the `properties()` method, e.g.:

```
var tasks = new Pouchyng('tasks', 'http://localhost:5984', yngutils.ASC);
var config = {
  opts: {
    filter: function (doc) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}; 
tasks.properties({ changes: config, to: config, from: config });
```